# Using if to compare strings c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare strings then have it write hi if the strings are equal.
But whenever I enter AS I get nothing AS being the string i want to compare my input against.

Here is my code.

```
using System;

namespace testing121
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            long vrt;
            bool run;
            string pass = ("AS");
            run = true;
            string vrt2;
            while (run)
            {
                if (long.TryParse (Console.ReadLine (), out vrt)) {
                    vrt2 = Convert.ToString (vrt);
                    if (String.Equals (pass, vrt2) ) {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Hi");
                    }
                }
            }}}}
```

Comment: How could a long value be equal to `AS` ? And you have an infinite loop.

Comment: You should know first the difference between data types. just saying,.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code just doesn't make sense. You're entering `AS` but then checking if it can be converted to a `long` as part of your condition for equality. Just do this;

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
   string pass = "AS";

   if (Console.ReadLine() == pass)
       Console.WriteLine("hi");
}
```

Then, if you want to put that in a loop or whatever go for it. But I recommend starting with the simplest most basic thing. When you run this program and enter `AS` it will print `hi`

Comment: very simple and very effective xD

Answer (score 0):

Because when you check your `if
(long.TryParse
(Console.ReadLine (), out
vrt))` the result of the `TryParse` is always `False` as you don't provide a number as long.
And the console will not write you `Hi`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this...

```
string pass = "AS";

            if (pass.Equals(Console.ReadLine()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("hi");   
            }
```